# java.lang.NullPointerException in session factory building hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, wildfly-10

I am trying to create a session factory object in hibernate 5. It throws null pointer exception while creating session factory object.
This is the error

```
Context Path:/cvgest
Servlet Path:/api
Path Info:/person/1
Query String:null
Stack Trace
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:168)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:411)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And this is my code

```
package com.goodotcom.cvgest.util;

import com.goodotcom.cvgest.model.Category;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

import java.io.File;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

My RESTService

```
package com.goodotcom.cvgest.api;

import com.goodotcom.cvgest.model.Person;
import com.goodotcom.cvgest.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/person")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PersonResourceRESTService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
    public Person lookupPersonById(@PathParam("id") int id){
        Person person;
        Session session= HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        person=session.get(Person.class,id);
        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
        return person;
    }    

}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/cv_gest
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      cv_gest
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      cv_gest
   </property>
      <property name="cache.provider_class">
         org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
      </property>

      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
      <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

      <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
      <mapping resource="skill.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="person.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="category.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.goodotcom.cvgest</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <resteasy.version>3.0.16.Final</resteasy.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>${project.groupId}-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <!--<plugins>-->
            <!--<plugin>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>-->
                <!--<configuration>-->
                    <!--<skip>true</skip>-->
                <!--</configuration>-->
            <!--</plugin>-->

            <!--<plugin>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
                <!--<configuration>-->
                    <!--<source>1.6</source>-->
                    <!--<target>1.6</target>-->
                <!--</configuration>-->
            <!--</plugin>-->
        <!--</plugins>-->
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jboss-deploy</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>7.4.Final</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>deploy</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <username>admin</username>
                                    <password>password</password>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>jboss-undeploy</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>7.4.Final</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>deploy</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>undeploy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <username>admin</username>
                                    <password>password</password>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Person.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.goodotcom.cvgest.model.Person" table="person">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the person detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <set name="skills" cascade="save-update" table="person_has_skill">
         <key column="person_id"/>
         <many-to-many column="skill_id" class="com.goodotcom.cvgest.model.Skill"/>
      </set>

      <property name="cf" column="cf" type="string"/>
      <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
      <property name="surname" column="surname" type="string"/>
      <property name="email" column="email" type="string"/>
      <property name="tel" column="tel" type="string"/>
      <property name="pathCv" column="path_cv" type="string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Entity Person

```
package com.goodotcom.cvgest.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "cf", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String cf;
    @Column(name = "name", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "tel", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String tel;
    @Column(name = "path_cv", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String pathCv;

    private Set<Skill> skills;

    public Person(){}

    public Person(int id, String cf, String name, String surname, String email, String tel, String pathCv) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cf = cf;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.pathCv = pathCv;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCf() {
        return cf;
    }

    public void setCf(String cf) {
        this.cf = cf;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getPathCv() {
        return pathCv;
    }

    public void setPathCv(String pathCv) {
        this.pathCv = pathCv;
    }

    public Set<Skill> getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(Set<Skill> skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }
}
```

Comment: since no exception is thrown from your code (no ```com.goodotcom``` in stack trace), it looks like "id" is not getting bound to path param somehow, and end ups null - which cannot be cast to primitive int.  you might want to investigate that.

Comment: The problem arises in that line code Session session= HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();